# How to use same Promise more than one time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
// App.js
sites[site_name].search(value).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
});

// SearchClass.js
Search.prototype.search = function(search) {
    var self = this;

    this.params['wa'] = search;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        self.resolve = resolve;
        self.reject  = reject;

        request(SEARCH_URL + '?' + querystring.stringify(self.params), function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                // Some code

                for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {

                    // Some Code

                    request(SEARCH_URL + '?' + querystring.stringify(self.params), function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
                            self.resolve(body);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

In my `app.js` I have a list of sites which I need to parse. The results from all sites  I need to show as one list. In my search class I search for different pages on selected site and then via promise return my results. Currently I getting data only from first `resolve` call. Is it possible somehow to use it multiply times?

Comment: save the promise returned by .search ... call .then as many times as you need

Comment: @JaromandaX I don’t know how much times it will be returned... For each request it can be different.

Comment: looking at your code again ... you can't do that .. a Promise is resolved/rejected once and once only ... any subsequent calls to resolve/reject are ignored ... you need an array of promises and promise.all

Comment: @JaromandaX as I said before I cant do that because  search returns not one value, but a lot of them

Comment: in that case you don't understand promises or promise.all

Comment: What is `pages` and where does it come from? Your code does not seem to make any use of it.

Comment: @Tomalak - that's probably in `some code`

Answer (score 2):

Create an array variable before the loop, and instead of resolving the "parent promise" , push a new Promise to the array for every request in the loop. Then after the loop use `Promise.all' to wait for all promises, then resolve the parent promise.

Something like this:

```
// SearchClass.js
Search.prototype.search = function(search) {
  var self = this;

  this.params['wa'] = search;

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      request(SEARCH_URL + '?' + querystring.stringify(self.params), function (error, response, body) {
            if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                return reject(error || response.statusCode);
            }

            var promises = [];

            for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
                promises.push( new Promise(resolve,reject){
                    request(SEARCH_URL + '?' + querystring.stringify(self.params), function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                            resolve(body);
                        }
                        else {
                            reject(error || response.statusCode);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            resolve(Promise.all(promises));
      });
  });
};
```

Mind you, I haven't tried it out (sorry, I know that makes it a poor answer) I might have fallen in some logic trap, but I think you'll get the logic behind it at least.

Comment: I'd have gotten rid of the `self.resolve` and `self.reject`  - resolve/reject are in scope so you don't need anything like that

Comment: `Promise.all(promises).then( function(){ self.resolve(promises); });` is the same as `resolve(Promise.all(promises));` - the latter is probably better, what if one of the inner promises rejects - your code wont ever reject the "outer" promise in that case

Comment: Yes, I can see that now than you mention it, lesson learned! (edited again)

Comment: now your answer looks very close to what I was about to post until you posted the answer ... I'd also `reject(error || response.statusCode)` in both places - to get some indication of error at least :p

Comment: also in the first reject ... `return reject()` - otherwise the inner code will run despite the error condtion